# pydicom : Dataset does not have attribute 'TransferSyntaxUID'

Tags: python, matlab, dicom, itk, pydicom

Hi I'm suffering from reading DICOM files with pydicom

This post is different from 
[pydicom 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'TransferSyntaxUID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492420/pydicom-dataset-object-has-no-attribute-transfersyntaxuid)

Here's my code

```
import dicom
dicom.read_file(file,force=True)
```

this causes an error

```
        AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-32-a32aef2d2178> in <module>()
    ----> 1 dicom.read_file(raw_path + pat_lst[0] + '\\' + pat_dcm_lst[0],force=True)

    D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dicom\filereader.pyc in read_file(fp, defer_size, stop_before_pixels, force)
        612     try:
        613         dataset = read_partial(fp, stop_when, defer_size=defer_size,
    --> 614                                force=force)
        615     finally:
        616         if not caller_owns_file:

    D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dicom\filereader.pyc in read_partial(fileobj, stop_when, defer_size, force)
        520     if preamble:
        521         file_meta_dataset = _read_file_meta_info(fileobj)
    --> 522         transfer_syntax = file_meta_dataset.TransferSyntaxUID
        523         if transfer_syntax == dicom.UID.ImplicitVRLittleEndian:
        524             pass

    D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dicom\dataset.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
        254         if tag not in self:
        255             raise AttributeError("Dataset does not have attribute "
    --> 256                                  "'{0:s}'.".format(name))
        257         else:  # do have that dicom data_element
        258             return self[tag].value

    AttributeError: Dataset does not have attribute 'TransferSyntaxUID'.
```

I think something goes wrong when anonymizing. 
I wanna know why this occurs.

Is deleting TransferSyntaxUID related with DICOM standard?

And, I can read through `MATLAB`, `VTK`, `ITK` but `pydicom`

So now what I'm trying to do is set TransferSyntaxUID manually via `SimpleITK` and read again via `pydicom`.

I'll let you know when this works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The pydicom repository has an update which is tolerant of a missing transfer syntax.  As a workaround until the next release, you could modify a couple of lines in filereader.py as shown [here](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/commit/9b91f7bcf493549c9e6f4a1c573385678db91b52)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the DICOM standard it appears that Transfer Syntax UID (0002,0010) is a mandatory tag. It is a [type 1 tag](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part10/chapter_7.html) which indicates it [is required](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part05/sect_7.4.html).

While this is what the standard says, libraries are likely able to read such files even with this tag missing. I am guessing this is because the standard also defines a [default transfer syntax](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part05/chapter_10.html).

With regard to setting values with SimpleITK, that should definitely work. Also, if you need to verify that your files comply with the standard you can use David Clunie's [dicom3tools](http://www.dclunie.com/dicom3tools.html), specifically dciodvfy and dcdump.

Comment: HI zivy, yeah thanks for your answer, I agree with your opinion that Transfer Syntax is mandatory, but I'm wondering anonymize protocol in the DICOM standard allows empty Transfer Syntax, As referred in Table E.1-1 from PS 3.15.
[PS.3.15 pdf](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/pdf/part15.pdf)

Comment: Hi JessieB, unfortunately anonymization is beyond my DICOM expertise. I am pretty skeptical with respect to anonymizers following the DICOM specification given that the anonymized data is not intended for use in patient treatment. I suspect it is common that they don't follow the standard (just an opinion based on personal experience with software development in general).